# Links are not working, but when I inspect them they are

Tags: html, hyperlink

Hi stackoverflow community. I have a strange issue with the links on my website. They are not clickable on the browser, however, when I inspect them I can click on them. Did anyone experienced the same problem and can share the solution for that?

HTML:

```
<p>jbfhjdbsfkbvk<a class="brexit" href="Articles_1.html">... [Continue to the full article]</a></p>
```

HTML of one section:

```
<div class="list_of_reviews_1">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
</ul>
<img src="for left column.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens"/>
<p>kjbngfugjdbgidbgkdsbgsdfbgkjdbgs<a class="brexit" href="Articles_1.html">... [Continue to the full article]</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us anymore details, like the browser you're using? Maybe you can show us your relevant code?

Comment: I tried on Firefox, Chrome and IE. In none of them links are working. Another div is using the same link and it works fine.

Comment: Could the problem be that I have 6 links like that sharing the same class for styling in CSS?

Comment: There's no way to know what the problem could be unless you can show an example that replicates the issue.

Comment: this particular html I shared is not working. What exactly an example would look like?

Comment: If I try your HTML it works: https://jsfiddle.net/9878fnbb/ You'll have to show enough code so that when we try it, it doesn't work in the same way that it doesn't work in your real project.

Comment: That's the thing there is nothing wrong with the code. And I doubt CSS can cause troubles cause it would just implement the same format for all the links. Seems like some sort of a bug rather than a code issue.

Comment: Just had a bit of reading on this and one of the reasons might be that when elements are positioned they might overlap, relatively becoming a layer between the anchor and the mouse. I don't know how much positioning might have overlapped in my case, but I provided the html in my edited question is the code for one section where I experience the issue.

Comment: Answering my questions. The theory I provided was correct for me. Seems like either the image or the title was overlapping with the paragraph. So I input z-index:5 in CSS for <p> giving it a priority and that solved the issue. Now link is clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some css put image or p tag and assign index they possibly overlap

```html
p {
 
    z-index: 5;

}
```

Comment: where habve you been :) but thank you. Now it will be a great thread for a beginner like me if he has an issue he has got a fully fledged response.

Comment: ohh great tick my answer. i upvoted your question to give some reputition

Comment: Thank you Masroor_Shah. Glad it is helpful

Comment: now tick my answer as correct answer below upvote and downvote there is Tick sign